# How to change Entity Framework DB First connection programmatically

Tags: c#, entity-framework, connection-string

I'm working on `C# WinForms` project, I use `Entity Framework DB First` approach to connect with a `SQL Server database`.

By default `Entity Framework` generated a `context class` named `GVentesEntities`

**`GVentesEntities` context class :**

```
public partial class GVentesEntities : DbContext
    {
        public GVentesEntities()
            : base( "name=GVentesEntities" )
        {
        }
    
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }
    
//Some Entitites here
    }
```

so please **is there any way or method to change programmatically the connection infos like server name or database name ?** massive thanks in advance.

Comment: You're already doing this. You're passing the connection name in the construcgtor already. [This constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbcontext.-ctor?view=entity-framework-6.2.0#System_Data_Entity_DbContext__ctor_System_String_) accepts either a connection name or full connection string

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos but how can I change it , and the EF who pass the connection name in the constructor

Comment: Add a `string` parameter to your constructor and pass the name of the connection you want. How often do you expect to change connections? You can store the connection strings in your config files and select them by name. Or you can construct the connection string at runtime and pass it to the constructor.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Please sir after your permission can you write some examples with explanation and really I appreciate it for you and massive thanks in advance for your time and effort sir.

Comment: `public GVentesEntities(string nameOrConnectionString) : base( nameOrConnectionString ) { }`

Comment: but what I should pass inside `nameOrConnectionString` as value, please can you provide me an example